# How to use pyspark percentile_approx to get median of a column and save it as a value independently?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, median

I want to get the median of the total_amount column and save itself for further using, here is my data set:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|PULocationID|DOLocationID|trip_distance|passenger_count|total_amount|
+------------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|          90|          68|          0.8|            1.0|         8.8|
|         113|          90|          0.9|            1.0|         8.8|
|          88|         232|          2.8|            1.0|        13.8|
|          79|         249|          1.4|            1.0|        12.3|
|         142|         238|          2.0|            0.0|        12.3|
|         114|          90|          1.6|            1.0|        12.8|
|          90|         144|          1.8|            1.0|        13.3|
|         114|          48|          2.0|            1.0|       14.75|
|          48|         152|          5.7|            1.0|        22.3|
|         234|         148|          1.8|            1.0|       14.75|
|          79|         141|          3.5|            2.0|        17.3|
```

and my code is :

```
processed.sort(processed.total_amount.asc())
processed.show()

median = FN.expr("percentile_approx(total_amount, 0.5, 1000000)")

print(median)
```

However it gives me non-sense as:

```
Column<'percentile_approx(total_amount, 0.5, 1000000)'>
```

it seems the median is not calculated at all

I also tried:

```
processed.agg(FN.expr("percentile_approx('total_amount', 0.5, 10000)")).show()
```

where the result is null

Comment: when i run `processed.agg(FN.expr("percentile_approx('total_amount', 0.5, 10000)")).show()` with a sample pyspark dataframe, i'm not able to reproduce your error unless i make the `total_amount` column entirely `null`. what does `processed.printSchema()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the agg function to calculate the median of a column:

```
median = df.agg(expr("percentile_approx(total_amount, 0.5)")).collect()[0][0]
print("The median is: ", median)
df = df.withColumn("median", lit(median))
```

Comment: cheers! you save my life :-) could you also kindly tell me how to add this result to the datafram as a column with all the same number or only one number, in case I need this operation further, really appreciate your time!

Comment: You can add it as a column using withColumn and lit() function in spark, I updated my answer

Comment: If it was MySQL you could just be like AVG(column) and you are done.    Side note, if you ARE using a database, do your calculations in the DB not on the front end when possible.